# Am I using conversion specifiers wrong or something? scanf() isn't working in c

Tags: c, scanf

scanf() isnt working properly when I use the following lines of code in c:

```
double withdraw = 0;

scanf("%.2lf",&withdraw);

printf("\n\nWithdraw %.2lf?",&withdraw);
```

and this:

```
double withdraw = 0;

scanf("%.2lf",withdraw);

printf("\n\nWithdraw %.2lf?",withdraw);
```

and this:

```
double withdraw = 0;

scanf("%.2lf",&withdraw);

printf("\n\nWithdraw %.2lf?",withdraw);
```

and finally this:

```
double withdraw = 0;

scanf("%.2lf",withdraw);

printf("\n\nWithdraw %.2lf?",&withdraw);
```

input into scanf() is ALWAYS this:

```
1
```

output of withdraw is ALWAYS this:

```
0.00
```

Please help. This seems so crazy to me!

Comment: `printf("\n\nWithdraw %.2lf?",&withdraw);` --> `printf("\n\nWithdraw %.2lf?",withdraw);`...remove `&` in print calls.

Comment: I've tried all 4 versions of the posted codeblocks thats why its seems wierd to me.

Comment: The 3rd variation of the code meets your requirements and still outputs 0.00

Comment: @Teddy...eh? Isn't the conversion specification still invalid?

Comment: Why didn't you check the return value from `scanf()`?  It wasn't returning `1`, was it?  Always check the status of input operations — make sure you get what you're expecting to get, and do something about it if you don't.'

Comment: Hi Jon. I checked to make sure. The issue was, that I couldn't get `scanf()` 
 to work properly because `scanf()` doesn't accept precision. I just adjusted my code by removing the precision on `scanf()` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your code is wrong. You cannot use *precisions* (`".<int>"`) with `fscanf()` family, that's invalid. This causes causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2/p3, *`fscanf()`*

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`.
>   After the `%`, the following appear in sequence:
>
> — An *optional* assignment-suppressing character `*`.
>
> — An *optional* decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the maximum field width
>   (in characters).
>
> — An *optional* length modifier that specifies the size of the receiving object.
>
> — A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.

and, p13

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

---

That said, do not use trial and error,  [undefined behaviors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) are tricky to catch and understand. read the manual pages for proper format specifier for any argument type.

Comment: Thank you guys so much!  I fixed my problem by taking away the precision in scanf()!

Comment: @Yunnosch Appreciate your comment, I've made modifications, though I ___strongly___ believe the earlier one was absolutely justified, the first stepping stone of learning is to learn to admit you're wrong and willing to correct that. If, __iff__, there's a culture which prevents this, I'm not very sure of the future continuing on that path. No hard feelings, nothing personal.

Answer (score 0):

As your compiler is telling you

```
warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat=]
```

So you cannot specify precision with this type of format specifier

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ the compiler must be bad because it didn't catch it.

Comment: @TeddyBearWithACape You must use `-Wall` option with your compiler. Best using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @TeddyBearWithACape Dev-C++ is an IDE, not a compiler. Your compiler might be `gcc`.

Comment: I understand that Dev-Cpp is an IDE that's why said the compiler not Dev-Cpp.  Useful to know that it may be `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

The following could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double withdraw = 0;

    scanf("%lf", &withdraw);
    printf("\n\nWithdraw %.2lf?", withdraw);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the difference and its reason. Also "could work" sounds like untested, which I am convinced is not what you mean. Maybe "this could work for you, the trick is ...". Just for better appreciation of your helpful answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch   Thank you for your suggestions. The reason is that you can't use '.' in scanf.